Does dask bag preserve order when using sequential dask.bag.map operations
It is stated that dask bags do not preserve order. However, the example given for dast.bag.map does something that implies that order is preserved, or at least predictable, in https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.bag.map.html
Specifically the example I'm referring to is this:
import dask.bag as db
b = db.from_sequence(range(5), npartitions=2)
b2 = db.from_sequence(range(5, 10), npartitions=2)
from operator import add
db.map(add, b, b2).compute()
[5, 7, 9, 11, 13]

This implies that the two bags are kept aligned. i.e. the second element of b is added to the second element of b2. My question: is this alignement is guaranteed? i.e. would you ever get the second element of b added to the third element of b2?
For completeness, I'll ask a related question. Suppose your graph splits and then recombines. Is the alignment guaranteed to be maintained? As a concrete example, suppose I want to compute x**2 + x**3 for every element in a bag. Would I be garanteed to maintain alignment and get the correct answer for each element of the bag x the following code?
import dask.bag as db
x = db.from_sequence(range(5), npartitions=2)
from operator import add, pow
x2 = db.map(pow, x, 2)
x3 = db.map(pow, x, 3)
x2_plus_x3 = db.map(add, x2, x3).compute()


Yes, it does appear to preserve order.  The function from_sequence creates a list from the input iterable, chunking as needed, and passes that list(s) to a Bag.  The Bag simply holds that data.
The map functions is an alias for dask.bag.core.bag_map.  In this function the args that are Bag objects are collected to a list and eventually passed to dask.highlevelgraph.HighLevelGraph.from_collections.  Which also does not rearranging of the elements, but simply puts them into a dictionary.
The HighLevelGraph is used to compute the output of the return type.  No where does dask rearrange the internal elements that were passed in at the beginning.

Thanks. So in what sense are bags unordered collections? That is how they are defined in the dask documentation.

Correct.  The mathematical construct of a bag is that it does not preserve order.  The current implementation of a bag in dask does, though it is not guaranteed to do so in the future.  It is kinds of like dictionaries pre-python 3.6.  The order seemed to be preserved, but was not guaranteed.

So, I think that is core to my question.  If at some point in the future, order is no longer preserved, would the examples I show in my question suddenly stop working? I am planning on writing code that relies on these type of relationships between bags being maintained between successive mapping operations. If I can't be sure the code will work in the future, I want to find a different implementation approach.

Pin your version of dask
